# How to debug the `figwheel-sidecar` project?

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

How can the `figwheel-sidecar` project be running on my own machine with my Emacs so I can debug into it?

I tried to `cider-jack-in`, it works, but how to let the clojurescript project depends on it and let Emacs run the local version of `figwheel-sidecar`?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Using-the-Figwheel-REPL-within-NRepl#integration-with-emacscider

Key steps

```
;; ~/.emacs.el or ~/.emacs.d/init.el

(require 'cider)
(setq cider-cljs-lein-repl
      "(do (require 'figwheel-sidecar.repl-api)
           (figwheel-sidecar.repl-api/start-figwheel!)
           (figwheel-sidecar.repl-api/cljs-repl))")
```

`M-x cider-jack-in-clojurescript [RET]`